# Is there a reason I cannot declare public in class? 

Tags: php

```
class struct {
public $variable=$_SESSION['Example'];
}
```

How do I call a Session and put it into a variable in php classes?

Comment: 4 equally valid identical solutions below :) sessions wai u no work?!11!

Comment: As $_SESSION is a super global variable, why would you need to assign it to a variable when you can just use it anywhere directly as $_SESSION['Example'] Creating extra varialbe and copying data to it is not very efficient. The only reason would be if you think that value of 'Example' in session can change after you instantiate your object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

```
class struct {
 public $variable;
 public function __construct(){
   session_start();
   $this->variable = $_SESSION['Example'];
 }
}
```

Comment: You beat the top too the session_start(); +1

Answer (score 3):

```
class struct {
  public $variable;

  public function __construct(){
    session_start();
    $this->variable = $_SESSION['Example'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Properties can only have literal defaults, not arbitrary expressions. The simplest way to do this is:

```
class Struct {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variable = $_SESSION['Example'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not set any properties in the definition unless they are a constant, e.g. `TRUE`, `array()`, etc.

In the `__construct()` you may set it.

Comment: Is `__FILE__ `a constant? I can do like this `public $var=__FILE__`

Comment: @WhoAmI Yes, it is a magic constant, and [it works](http://codepad.org/9Axu9Xsk).